# Buzzing sound from every sound output (internal speakers, headphones) on Macbook. Hardware or software?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hardware, headphones, speakers

I recently bought an old Macbook Pro ([A1398](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.6-15-mid-2012-retina-display-specs.html)).

The internal speakers make a **buzzing sound**; anything plugged into the headphone jack also does.

**Is there any way to determine if it is a software problem or a hardware problem?**

(I know the hardware explanation seems unlikely, but *only* the buzz in the internal speakers varies with the volume, so the cause may in principle be different).

Hopefully the answer can be of interest for anyone who wants to learn how to tell a hardware problem from a software problem in this kind of situation!

Comment: Does the buzzing change if plugged/unplugged?

Comment: If it's software the sound will turn up & down with the volume control. if it's hardware, it won't.

Comment: @ Tetsujin : if you are right, then it is a software problem for the jack port and a hardware problem on the internal speakers. But e.g. a blown speaker (hardware problem) will make a stronger buzz with a louder volume, so I'm not sure if you are right..

@JaimeSantaCruz : I don't know what you mean so I'm not sure if I am answering your question. The buzz coming from the jack port is more uniform and less sound-dependent than the one in the internal speakers. I barely hear anything there, but the internal speaker sound is hearable despite the buzz.

Comment: I meant to say if it changed when you plugged the computer charger, apologies for the ambiguous comment.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I just checked and no, it doesn't make a difference!